# Allowing IP Ranges in McAfee Endpoint Security

Tags: networking, virtualbox, security, firewall

I have "McAfee Endpoint Security" on my Windows 10 box. And I have "Oracle VM VirtualBox" installed on the same machine and the VMs used to get the following IP Range `192.168.1.0/24`

I see "McAfee Endpoint Security" is blocking this IP Range. I have verified this by Disabling the "Endpoint Security Firewall". Only after disabling the Firewall, I am able to access the machines. How can I allow these IP range so that McAfee don't block them?

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following way:

1. Open **McAfee Security Center**.
2. Navigate to **Internet and Network->Advanced->Disabled IPs** in the left.
3. View whether the IP address (192.168.1.0/24) in this range is displayed in the list of prohibited IPs, if there is any, we can delete these IPs.

Comment: I believe McAfee Security Center is different from McAfee Endpoint Security. Because I don't see the above suggested options in my side.